# Detect if remote host is running Windows or Samba

Tags: linux, windows, samba, nmap

From a Linux server, how can I quickly determine if a remote machine is running Windows or Samba?

I want to run commands on remote Windows machines (XP and 7) to list the installed software and versions. And I want to run these commands from a Linux server (using [winexe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/)).

To find the Windows hosts, I use this nmap command:

```
nmap -oG - -T4 -p T:445 192.168.1.0/24 | awk '{print $2, $3}'
```

However, I also get all the Samba servers and a few printers.

Is there a simple way, through additional nmap options or through a separate command, to get only the real Windows machines, and avoid sending irrelevant Windows commands to non-Windows servers and devices?

**Update:**

I followed pferate's suggestion and used `-O`. I hadn't tried it because I thought it would be slow and unreliable, but it works well in this situation. I now use this to detect real Windows machines:

```
nmap -oG - -T4 -p T:445 -O --max-os-tries 1 192.168.1.0/24 | grep '445/open/.* Windows' | awk '{print $2, $3}'
```

Comment: Try adding -sV.. it will slow up the scan alot, but will show detailed(..er) version info, which you can grep then

Comment: `-sV` does indeed make it extremely slow as you warned. It does display "Samba..." reliably in my networks, but unfortunately, it doesn't differentiate Macs from Win7 machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using nmap's OS Detection option, `-O`.

```
nmap -O host
```

You can also try looking at the `OS String` or `Server String` for the host.  Although it can be changed, the default Server string for Samba is `Samba Server Version %v`.  I'm not sure what Windows' default server string is for all of the variants, but on Win7 SP1 I have `Windows 7 Professional 6.1`.

On my Linux Samba server the OS string is `Unix` and on Win7 SP1 it is `Windows 7 Professional 7601 Service Pack 1`.

```
$ smbclient -L host

Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba x.y.z]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
```

Since these values can be changed, you can't trust it completely; but it can give you some initial insight.